# access public information of facebook profile through Graph api without access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There are some public information about a facebook profile which any other person with facebook
 account can easily see by typing that profile URL address in address bar. How can we access that
 information through Graph API without access token. because i have signed up for facebook developer
account this means I have facebook account and i can see that information (which is availble publicly) by login in from
 my account. Does facebook allows facebook developer to access that info from api with out any access token. 
e.g home town, birthday, Studied at, Friends (if made public) etc of any facebook profile. Kindly help me in this if someone knows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have a look at the API yourself? Which part of the documentation was not clear?

Comment: Thanks for your quick Reply.
I have signed up for facebook developer account and I want to fetch all public information of any user.
I have opened Graph API explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer 
when I type XXXProfileIDXXX?fields=birthday , as response, I only recieves 
{
  "id": "XXXProfileIDXXX"
}
but if we visit timeline address like https://www.facebook.com/name, we can see birthday in about
where as Graph API is not returning Birthday even if it is public. It's also not returning other public info of profile which can be seen by visiting profile URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just  because something is publicly available via fb dot com doesn't mean it is via the API, too. You need to request public_profile permission from the user, otherwise you cannot access that data via the API.
To access the user's birthday (if available) it requires user_birthday permission.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was really helpful.